# How to stop media_sideload_image from running when deleting a post?

Tags: functions, uploads, media-library

I have a code that downloads an image and saves it to the media library when you save a post that uses a certain block. The code runs perfect but downloads the image again if you delete the post. How do you prevent `media`_sideload_image` from running when you delete a post?

My code :

```
function post_extra_save( $post_id, $post){
global $pagenow;
if ($pagenow == 'post.php') { // if creating a new post
    if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
        $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
        foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
            if ( $block['blockName'] === 'acf/opby-link' ) { // if block is used
                static $updated = false;
                // If title has already been set once, bail.
                if ( $updated ) {
                    return;
                }
                // Since we're updating this post's title, set this
                // variable to true to ensure it doesn't happen again.
                $updated = true;    
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                $url     = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/04/08/21/04/buildings-7120297_1280.jpg";
                media_sideload_image($url, $post_id, null, 'id');
            }// End if check opby-video.
        }
    }
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_extra_save', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just check if the post **status** is `trash`, and if so, don't run the rest of your code. E.g. (PS: I intentionally used strict comparison, i.e. using `===` as in `$pagenow === 'post.php'`)

```php
function post_extra_save( $post_id, $post ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow === 'post.php' && 'trash' !== $post->post_status) {
        ... your code.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, run your code only if the post status is `publish` or that it's in one of a whitelisted/allowed statuses list. E.g.

```php
function post_extra_save( $post_id, $post ) {
    global $pagenow;

    $allowed_statuses = array( 'publish', 'private' ); // list of allowed post statuses

    if ($pagenow === 'post.php' && in_array( $post->post_status, $allowed_statuses )) {
        ... your code.
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew there was a way to execute functions on published posts. Thanks for the help.